# Wood screw dimensions not coming out right

Tags: screws

According to [various specifications on the internet](https://www.mcfeelys.com/screw_size_comparisons), a #12 wood screw is supposed to have a head diameter of 0.438". However, when I measure #12 wood screws that I have, their head diameter is 0.403". What is the explanation for this?

Answer (score 3):

The chart you're referring to doesn't specify the exact dimensions of a #12 screw to have a head diameter of .438". The chart specifies a maximum diameter of .438" and a minimum diameter of .389".  So your measurement of .403" diameter is right in line or within the limits of the production screws. These are the tolerances set for production and since they won't be used on the space shuttle, they can vary a bit.

Comment: Of course they won't - the space shuttle wasn't made of wood :-)

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact  There is a wooden satellite going to be launch soon.  https://www.space.com/first-wooden-satellite-will-launch-in-2021

Comment: @crip659  But will it have #12 flat head screws in it??  :-)